# Tengo problemas al ejecutar la migración en Laravel 7.12

Tags: artisan, laravel-7

Buenas tengo una pregunta ya que me esta dando error a la hora de ejecucar una migración ya que al definir una clave foránea me da error. Estoy haciendo una relación de 1 a N de un Usuario y Roles.

**Migración de Usuarios:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('Id')->comment('ID');
            $table->bigInteger('IdRol')->comment('IdRol');
            $table->integer('Codigo')->comment('Código');
            $table->string('Cedula', 20)->comment('No. de Cédula');
            $table->string('Nombre', 30)->comment('Nombre');
            $table->string('Apellido', 30)->comment('Apellido');
            $table->string('EMail', 50)->nullable()->comment('E-Mail');

            $table->foreign('IdRol')
                   ->references('Id')->on('roles')
                   ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });
    }
```

**Migración de Roles:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('Id')->comment('ID');
            $table->string('Nombre', 20)->unique()->comment('Nombre');
            $table->string('Slug', 20)->unique()->comment('Slug');
            $table->text('Descripcion')->nullable()->comment('Descripción');
            $table->enum('Acceso', ['Si', 'No'])->nullable()->comment('Acceso');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Este es el error en el PHP ARTISAN**
[image: Ejecutando PHP Artisan]

No se cual es el **error**, no se si tengo mal el tipo de dato de la clave foránea en la migración de **Usuarios** o que será?.

---

Agregue `$table->unsignedBigInteger('IdRol');` a la llave foránea pero me sigue mandando el mismo error. Ejecute la migración de **Role** (sigue siendo el mismo sin modificación) primero y luego la migración de **Usuario**.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('Id')->comment('ID');
            $table->integer('Codigo')->comment('Código');
            $table->string('Cedula', 20)->comment('No. de Cédula');
            $table->string('Nombre', 30)->comment('Nombre');
            $table->string('Apellido', 30)->comment('Apellido');
            $table->string('EMail', 50)->nullable()->comment('E-Mail');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('IdRol'); // Llave foránea

            $table->foreign('IdRol')->references('Id')->on('roles'); //Relación
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });
    }
```

No sera por mi versión de **Laravel 7.x**?
En ***Laravel 7.x*** la llave principal se define así: `$table->id();` pero en ***Laravel 5.8*** la llave principal se definia así: `$table->bigIncrements('id');` no se si por ahí va el asunto de la integridad de los tipos de datos para la *clave foránea*.

**en PHP ARTISAN:**

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `sistema-academico`.`usuari
os` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `us
uarios` add constraint `usuarios_idrol_foreign` foreign key (`IdRol`) references `rol
es` (`Id`))
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Laravel: Error al modificar FKs y Tablas auto referenciadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270325/laravel-error-al-modificar-fks-y-tablas-auto-referenciadas)

Comment: ¿O esta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/361184/92278

Comment: aún con unsignedBigInteger en la clave foránea me sigue dando el mismo error...

Comment: ¿Estás corriendo las migraciones en el orden correcto? ¿Primero roles y luego usuarios? No podrás referenciar a una columna de una tabla que aún no existe.

Comment: lo hize como me digiste ejecutando la migración de Roles primero y luego la de Usuarios y me manda el mismo error con unsignedBigInteger.

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta con cómo es el código actual y agrega los nombres de los archivos de las migraciones. Puedes agregarlo debajo de la pregunta original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu migracion falla porque estas asociando una foreign key a una tabla que no ha creado, para resolver esto, se debe crear una migración nueva en donde puedas agregar la FK, para ello se ejecuta el comando

```
php artisan serve make:migration add_rol_id_to_users_table --table=users
```

una vez que se haya creado la migración, escribes la FK que deseas agregar:

```
add_rol_id_to_users_table:

    public function up(){
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('rol_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Para la tabla users:

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->integer('Codigo')->comment('Código');
        $table->string('Cedula', 20)->comment('No. de Cédula');
        $table->string('Nombre', 30)->comment('Nombre');
        $table->string('Apellido', 30)->comment('Apellido');
        $table->string('EMail', 50)->nullable()->comment('E-Mail');

        $table->timestamps();
        
    });
}
```

Para la tabla roles:

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        
        $table->string('Nombre', 20)->unique()->comment('Nombre');
        $table->string('Slug', 20)->unique()->comment('Slug');
        $table->text('Descripcion')->nullable()->comment('Descripción');
        $table->enum('Acceso', ['Si', 'No'])->nullable()->comment('Acceso');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Tu método me sirvio, hize los pasos y si me funciono perfecto. Desde la versión 7 de Laravel con $table->foreignId('rol_id')... se agrega la llave foránea y tambien ahí mismo se relaciona con la otra tabla en una sola línea ya que en la versión 5.8 no era así y ese era mi enrredo. Mil gracias.